# How to hide element on render/update livewire?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have search button which will get removed on loading and the other one is loading... element which will showed on loading.

```
<button wire:loading.remove type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-end " wire:click="render">
     <i class="ri-search-2-line"></i></button>
<button wire:loading.delay type="button" class="btn btn-primary " >
     <div class="spinner-border" role="status"  style="width: 1rem; height: 1rem">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
     </div>
</button>
```

The issue is when any property get updated in the live wire component `wire:loading.remove` form the first button will not working, and both button will get displayed on update/render state of component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `spinner-border` class, which shows the loading animation, causes it to be shown even when not loading. You can wrap the loading button inside another `div` and put the `wire:loading` on that `div`:

```
<button wire:loading.remove type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-end " wire:click="generateReport">
    <i class="ri-search-2-line"></i>
</button>
<div wire:loading>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " >
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"  style="width: 1rem; height: 1rem">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Also, you can change the `wire:loading.delay` to `wire:loading` in the second button to prevent delay of loading animation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your code works pretty fine, because I just copied your code and everything is good

Comment: no there is issue on the update/render method